# what does the codes with the 'with' statement do?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, with-statement

When so many examples are non-self explanatory and the documentation not too helpful, Beginning Python I came across **with** statement used in a code as such:

```
def r_f(fn, n, vl):
    cn, rd = 0, 0
    with open(fn, 'r') as f:
        for value in f.readlines():
            rd += 1
            if rd > n:
                break
            if int(value) == vl:
                cn += 1

    return cn
```

after spending some hour on the internet I found something that gave me a quite understandable explanation that the with statement was meant to use multiple statements, but then again what that meant, I was not so sure of. After spending hours again, I found that the `open(fn, 'r')` code was meant to read the file with the given filename `(with other operations of 'w', etc.)`, but the following lines as the `f.readlines()`, are hard to find. Therefore, I have no idea what the above code does. My questions are therefore enlisted as:

1. What does the code exactly do?

   What exactly is the with statement and how's it using multiple
   statement?

   What is the as in the code for?

   What does the f.readline() implement in the code?

   Why is the comparison:

if int(value) == vl:
    cn += 1

even made?

Comment: Did you even try to google "with statement python"?

Comment: @PascalvKooten, yes sir, I googled it includes the Phreshing on programming, which halfway told me the answer(I included), I'm a non programmer and my first language is python, it's not that easy when I'm being self taught.

Comment: I'm also self taught; it should make you a google champion. I find the explanation for the first result (http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) on "with statement python" very easy to understand. If you find one result that is not clear then just look for the next explanation...

Comment: @PascalvKooten, thanks though I did find that page earlier, but you know I haven't even stepped foot on the try ... finally..... statement and am completely unaware of  the __xyz__things that are so much in the page, may I ask you which book did you follow when you were first learning Python?

Comment: No book, I just started with a goal: to create a simple GUI for some calculations using Python. If you don't understand something, try to substitute the parts you don't understand with "will make sense later". Then you should read it again in 2 months: most likely it will click then. For now, just using that code does allow you to read a file just fine, right? I guess rather than trying to focus on understanding the intrinsics, another approach can be just to try to get your things done, and learn a long the way. But I understand, it is not the simplest example.

Comment: In my case, I'm following a freely available python book, actually it's an excellent material, though some parts are poorly explained, perhaps, you learnt other languages before python? I started learning python After I detached myself to master Blender's api, afterwards started off for the language itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I commented to try explain;

```
#this is your standard method definition
def r_f(fn, n, vl):
        #these are local variables
        cn, rd = 0, 0
        #we are saying;
        #in the scope of this with statement, the variable f
        #is equal to the file object returned by open
        with open(fn, 'r') as f:
            #for every line in the file
            #(because readlines returns a list of all the lines)
            for value in f.readlines():
                #increment this variable by 1
                rd += 1
                #if rd is greater than n
                if rd > n:
                    #break out of this loop
                    break
                #if the integer representation of the line we read
                #is equal to v1
                if int(value) == vl:
                    #then increase this variable by 1
                    cn += 1
        #we return this value to the function that called us
        return cn
```

> What does the code exactly do?

It is counting the number of times some number appears in a file, but very hard to say though because its exact behavior depends on the arguments supplied at run time!

EDIT: As a follow up, I recommend reading the link @PascalvKooten posted in the comments, very clear explanation of exactly what the `with` statement is

Comment: wow this really hits it! thanks a tonne.

Answer (score 1):

You have to read documentations before you start reading source codes written by others.

Check [this official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) for `with` statements.

The function you've copied does following things: 
it gets three arguments. then it sets `cn` and `rd` variables to 0. `with open(fn, 'r') as f` means open file named `fn` in reading mode and call it `f` from now. Then you have the `for` loop who read each line of your currently open file, `f` and do something for each line. First it increments `rd`, if `rd` was bigger than `n` the loop breaks, otherwise if the value (converted `value` to an integer by int() function) is equal to vl, then it increments `cn` and returns it.